# Using attribute values in other attributes within the same attributes file in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Note: My example here is meant to display the context of my question, not a real-world example.

I have the following as an example in my `attributes/default.rb` file:

```
default[:php] = {
    version: '7.3',
    repository: 'ondrej/php',
    extensions: [
        "php7.3",
        "php7.3-common",
        "php7.3-gd",
        "php7.3-mysql",
        "php7.3-curl",
        "php7.3-intl",
        "php7.3-xsl",
        "php7.3-mbstring",
        "php7.3-zip",
        "php7.3-bcmath",
        "php7.3-iconv",
        "php7.3-soap",
        "php7.3-fpm",
        "libapache2-mod-php7.3"
    ],
    options: {
        :timezone => 'America/Los Angeles',
        :memory_limit => '2G',
        :max_execution_time => 1800,
        :zlib_output_compression => 'On',
        :session_save_path => '/var/lib/sessions'
    }
}
```

Next, I pass that to a template like so:

```
template '/home/vagrant/php_test.txt' do
    source node['url'] % {version: node['version']}
    source 'php_test.txt.erb'
    owner 'vagrant'
    group 'vagrant'
    mode '0755'
    variables(
        php: node[:php]
    )
end
```

And then I reference the values in my template like this:

```
PHP Version : <%= @php[:version] %>
PHP Repository : <%= @php[:repository] %>

PHP Extension List:
<% @php[:extensions].each do |extension| %>
<%= "#{extension}" %>
<% end %>

PHP Options List
<% @php[:options].each do |option, value| %>
<%= "#{option}: #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

This results in the following text file:

```
PHP Version : 7.3
PHP Repository : ondrej/php

PHP Extension List:
php7.3
libapache2-mod-php7.3
php7.3-common
php7.3-gd
php7.3-mysql
php7.3-curl
php7.3-intl
php7.3-xsl
php7.3-mbstring
php7.3-zip
php7.3-bcmath
php7.3-iconv
php7.3-soap
php7.3-fpm

PHP Options List
timezone: America/Los Angeles
memory_limit: 2G
max_execution_time: 1800
zlib_output_compression: On
session_save_path: /var/lib/sessions
```

Everything works fine; however, the DRY-ist in me sees all of those `7.3`'s in there and says, "Hey, why don't you just reference the value of `version` within the value of each extension in the list?"  So, I try this in my `attributes/default.rb` file:

```
...

extensions: [
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-common",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-gd",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-mysql",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-curl",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-intl",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-xsl",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-mbstring",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-zip",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-bcmath",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-iconv",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-soap",
    "php#{node[:php][:version]}-fpm",
    "libapache2-mod-#{node[:php][:version]}"
]

...
```

There are (at least) two problems with this.  First, it doesn't do what I expect.  When I loop over the array in my template, each of the values are printed as strings rather than interpolated.  Second, it breaks chef best practice as mentioned here: https://github.com/pulseenergy/chef-style-guide#attributes

So then, what's the best way to use the value of one attribute in the population of another?

In thinking about this, there are two options I can think of:

1. Use delayed interpolation as indicated here:
   https://coderanger.net/derived-attributes/

The issue I have with this is that I don't quite understand how the  suggested concept would work as my ruby skills aren't quite up to par.

2. Store the extensions without the `php-` suffix and then loop over them in a recipe and concatenate `php`, the version string, and the extensions into a single value per extension.  Store each of those in a new array which gets passed through to the template.

Is there another way to achieve this; possibly by forcing the `"php{node[:php][:version]}"` attributes to interpolate in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Chef, but reading that best practices page, derived attributes via delayed interpolation is the right approach here. It should be fairly straightforward:

```
extensions: [
  "php%{version}",
  "php%{version}-common",
  "php%{version}-gd",
  # ...
]
```

Then later, when you render it:

```
<% @php[:extensions].each do |extension| %>
<%= extension % @php %>
<% end %>
```

This is a little unobvious, but it works because `string % hash` will use the keys in `hash` to replace any named placeholders in the string. Hash values that don't exist as named placeholders are ignored.

```
"test: %{bang}" % {baz: "bin", bang: "bar"}
=> "test: bar"
```

Since your `@php` variable has a `:version` key, it will be substituted into the value of each extension string as it's rendered, if that string contains the placeholder `%{version}`.

You could do it more explicitly, as well:

```
# Create a hash with the one key:
<%= extension % {version: @php[:version]} %>

# Or, just create a hash by slicing out just the attribute you care about
<%= extension % @php.slice(:version) %>
```

Comment: another approach that is suggested by rubocop is using `format` which is technically the same but more declarative: `format "php-%{version}", { version: "1.2.3" } `

Comment: Agreed. I prefer `format`, but the Chef doc used `%` so I went with that.

Comment: Can you point me to the Chef doc? AFAIK Chef is heavily using `cookstyle` which is `rubocop` + some chef specific rules/modifications. https://github.com/chef/cookstyle

Comment: Heh, I just went off the link in the OP's post. If Chef prefers format, format it should be :)

Comment: Firstly, thanks a ton for spending the time on such a detailed response. I really appreciate it, and the explanation is very clear.  I've tried all three methods.  I'm convinced this is the answer; however, using any of the options you provided, Chef gives me an error in the template: "Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError: key{node[:php][:version]} not found".  That said, the variables DO actually compile properly: the hash is shown in the compiled resource. The first part of that shows that key: variables {:php=>{"version"=>"7.3"... so I'm a bit confused.  Thanks again for answering!

Comment: `:version` and `"version"` are different value in Ruby, so you may need to be using `["version"]` rather than `[:version]`. ActiveSupport has a version of Hash called HashWithIndifferentAccess which lets you use them interchangably, but that's probably not in play here. Based on the initial definition, the key should be `:version` but it's possible Chef is doing something mutative with it.

Comment: Ha.  Turns out the error was mine: I didn't quite read your extensions array properly and failed to recognize {version}.  Both of your examples work beautifully.  Thanks so much.  One last request if you don't mind:  I've been searching for some examples of how to use the format approach that was recommended.  I can't quite understand how to pass format the value of extension so it can be formatted, however.  Would you be willing to supply an example?  I'll go ahead and accept your answer!

Comment: `format("foo-%{version}", {version: "1.2.3"})` is the same as `"foo-%{version}" % {version: "1.2.3"}`. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-format